# Create Text file on OneDrive to set and get data

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp, onedrive

Is there any code snippet to assist me in that task?

- Authentication to OneDrive
- Save some variables in text file, upload that file to OneDrive.
- Get the variables (if exists) from OneDrive.

I work on Universal Windows 10 app and want users to save their settings on OneDrive to get them later from any other device.

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Create a simple text file at onedrive:\Apps\<your UWP name>\Some Folder\Some File.txt

// GetUniversalClient won't work until you associate your app with the store
var onedrive = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(new[] { "wl.signin", "onedrive.appfolder" });
await onedrive.AuthenticateAsync();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello onedrive")))
{
    await onedrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot
        .ItemWithPath("Some Folder/Some File.txt").Content
        .Request().PutAsync<Item>(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://dev.onedrive.com/index.htm) you can find samples and api documentations.